# What does "チョコボといっしょにあてのない方旅をしてる” mean?

Tags: particle-に, particle-と, particle-の

Let me specify. I'm playing a Japanese copy of "Final Fantasy V" and I come across sentences I don't know the full meaning of sometimes. I know it means something along the lines of: "My Chocobo and I are on a journey together with no destination", but bits of it confuse me.

If I'm not mistaken:

"チョコボ" is obviously Chocobo, "と" is the particle for "together" or "with", I'm not quite sure what "いっしょ" means, "に" is another particle (I don't know it's specific use here), "あてのない" means "no purpose" (assisted by the particle "の"), "方旅" means "journey", "を" is the particle for direct object, and "してる" means "I'm doing".

I've tried to work this out the best I can, but some parts of the sentence have stumped me so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The 「方」 makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe I put in the wrong kanji. It's hard to tell which kanji is on screen since I'm using an original SNES. I'll check it again

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this (bot) tweet](https://twitter.com/ff5_four_hearts/status/1246566270465499137), the correct phrase is おれは、バッツ。チョコボといっしょにあてのない旅をしてる…

Breaking down the sentence,

- おれは、バッツ。 I'm Butz.
- チョコボといっしょに together with Chocobo
- あてのない旅をしてる… on a journey without destination.

[あて](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A6/#jn-5005) generally means *target, objective*. の is a subject maker, あてのない as a whole means *targetless, destinationless*.

Grammatically, the subject ofthe second sentence (= Butz) is omitted. So it is おれは/チョコボといっしょに/あてのない旅をしてる… = I /  together with Chocobo / am making a destinationless journey.

---

Not sure of the spelling of Butz. Maybe Bartz?

Comment: Thank you! "バッツ" is a player chosen name, so I have no idea how it's pronounced either

Comment: Ah, I mean the 'official' (or default) name. It seems slightly differently depending on versions ([source](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Bartz_Klauser))